# How do i connect one table in a mySQL database to more than one other table via foreign keys?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

I have a users table, roles table and a notifications table. The user_id is the foreign key for linking users to notifications.

In my users class i am already accessing another table, roles via its foreignkey, role_id.
    As shown

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {`enter code here`

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String username;

    // Valid From
    @Column
    private Date validFrom;


    // Valid To
    @Column
    private Date validTo;

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))






    private Role role;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

How can i use the @JoinTable annotation to connect to the notifications table?
Its not accepting duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not will use @JoinTable annotation. The @JoinTable annotation is used only to @ManyToMany relationship.

You need create a new Entity with three field, and each field must has the @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn annotation.
For Instance:

```
@Entity
   @Table(name = "table_name")
   class NewEntity {

    //Id and anothers fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Users users;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Roles roles;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id")
    private Notifications notifications ;

    //getters and setters       
}
```